# Postgresql: split database between different machines

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

I want to partition a very large PostgreSQL 8.3 database. [Quoting the manual](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/ddl-partitioning.html),

> Partitioning can provide several
>   benefits:
>
> ...
>
> Seldom-used data can be
>   migrated to cheaper and slower storage
>   media.

What's the right way to relocate tables to another media or computer?
Adam

Comment: I'd always thought the partitioning the manual was referring to was the use of table inheriting and different tablespaces for the different partitions.  You could have a historical partition in a different tablespace that maybe didn't need to be on high speed storage.  Different tablespaces could be located on different physical disks.   Replication solves a whole other set and scale of issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are talking about is commonly referred to as Replication or Clustering, depending on how the system is set up.

What you want to do specifically is clustering, and [you can do it on PostgreSQL](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling#Clustering).

The wiki lists some of the existing solutions:

> - [Greenplum Database](http://www.greenplum.com/index.php?page=greenplum-database) (formerly Bizgres MPP), proprietary. Not so much a replication solution as a way to parallelize queries, and targeted at the data warehousing crowd. Similar to ExtenDB, but tightly integrated with PostgreSQL.
> - [GridSQL for EnterpriseDB Advanced Server](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products/gridsql.do) (formerly ExtenDB)
> - sequoia (jdbc, formerly known as c-jdbc)
> - [PL/Proxy](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PL/Proxy) - database partitioning system implemented as PL language.
> - [HadoopDB](http://db.cs.yale.edu/hadoopdb/hadoopdb.html) - A MapReduce layer put in front of a cluster of postgres back end servers. Shared-nothing clustering.

Comment: Don't forget Slony, can be a good solution as well. Or wait for PostgreSQL 9.0.